GitHub Autograder Tasty Handle Writing Exception
I'm unit testing the following Haskell function in Tasty for GitHub's autograder:
countLetters :: IO [Int]
countLetters = do 
               putStr "First entry: "
               x <- getLine
               putStr "Second entry: "
               y <- getLine
               putStr "Third entry: "
               z <- getLine
               return [length x, length y, length z]


With the following auto-grading code:
testCase "test_countLetters" $ do
         h <- openFile "/dev/null" ReadMode
         hDuplicateTo h stdin
         
         hPutStrLn stdin "Haskell Is Fun"
         result <- countLetters
         hClose h
         assertEqual "Count Letters" [7,2,3] result

I added the file to my "autograding.json" file, and am now getting the following error:
Exception: <stdin>: hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is not open for writing)
From my (newb) understanding, a closed handle means the file cannot take input or output, so it's erroring. I switched the "ReadMode" over to "WriteMode", and that also gives an error that hGetLine cannot be called due to the handle not being opened for reading.

You're trying to write to stdin which is an input stream and thus you cannot write to it.
